# Easy way to duplicate openshift application?

Tags: openshift

Is there an easy way to duplicate an openshift application?  This would not only copy the code, but also the environment variables and other settings?

I have one now that works well for testing, and I want to have another copy of it for production.

Comment: Nope! Actually, you should to have used something like deployment tool before.

Comment: Is there any deployment tools you recommend?

Comment: Well there is many tools out there like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) or Capistrano. I have used Fabric (because of my Python background) and [Openshif Action Hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of very easy ways to copy an OpenShift application.

1. Backup & Restore (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-backing-up-applications.html)
2. Clone an existing application (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/Cloning_an_Existing_Application.html)

Both sets of rhc commands should give you the desired copy of the application running on your account.